# Creating a list in one screen and then accessing it from another screen with passing the list as a parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, google-maps

I have 2 screens that I am working with in a flutter app.

Screen 1:
This screen gets property data from an API based on zipcode. In this screen, I create a list of markers to be used in Google Maps API to place markers at the addresses on screen 2. So for now, the list of markers is created and resides in screen 1 only.

Screen 2:
In this screen, I will retrieve the list of markers and use them to pass to the Google Maps API to display on the map in screen 2.

For now, I navigate from screen 1 to screen 2 using a NavigationBar at the bottom of the app.

When I navigate to screen 2, I want to be able to access the list of markers created in screen 1. What is the best way of doing this? I mean what is the best practice way of doing this? Should I make the list of markers a global?

This is a personal project that I am doing to learn flutter so the app really has no useful application other than for me to learn flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

In Screen 1, when you navigate to Screen 2, pass the list of markers as constructor parameters to Screen 2:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Screen2(markers: yourListOfMarkers),
  ),
);
```

In Screen 2, create a constructor that accepts the list of markers as a

```
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Marker> markers;

  Screen2({required this.markers});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use this.markers to access the list of markers in Screen 2.
    // You can now use it with Google Maps API or any other purpose.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen 2'),
      ),
      body: // Your content here,
    );
  }
}
```